# Algebraic topology and complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Happy new year!

Can algebraic topology help me to understand deeper complex analysis ?

If so, can you give me, please, an example of a book ? (the chapter that I need if it is not all the book).

Thank you !

Comment: I edit thank you !

Comment: maybe the notion of winding number, along with some of the theory of riemann surfaces.